# 403 on Setting up Apache on Amazon Basic AMI

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, amazon-ec2

I'm in the midst of setting up a standard web server on EC2. However, I'm just getting a 403 error on remote access, despite following tutorials (which describe a very simple process).

So far, I have

1. Installed httpd and associating
2. Mounted /var/www/vhosts/foo to an s3 bucket dir.
3. Installed php
4. Edited httpd conf adding a NameVirtualHost *:80, a

   > ```
   > <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/foo/*bar*">
   > Satisfy Any
   > Order Allow,Deny
   > Allow from all
   > </Directory>
   > ```

and a

```
SuexecUserGroup root root
```

and a

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias mydomain.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/foo/bar/htdocs
  CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/fooh/bar/logs/access.log common
  ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/foo/bar/logs/error.log
  SuexecUserGroup root root
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/vhosts/foo/cgi-bin.bar/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I'm aware root isn't great at this stage. But, until the problem is sorted I haven't gone about changing that.

I've restarted httpd - I just get 403 errors. I can see the hits on access.log on the subdomain etc. so it is getting through (via my foo.mydomain.com) - but it's not going past a 403 and I can't figure out a reason why. All the tutorials say this is mega easy.

Answer (score 0):

The error log should be the first point of call.  What does:

```
  /var/www/vhosts/foo/bar/logs/error.log
```

Show?

Comment: Simply:- [Tue Oct 25 11:06:21 2011] [error] [client x.x.x.x] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied

Comment: At a guess I'd say that the wildcard isn't working correctly.  Can you replace it with multiple directories?  Or the parent instead?  To see if that helps.

Comment: Have now got from <Directory "/foo/bar/yes"> - no change. However, I have managed to get it working with STANDARD /var/www/html useage - i.e. a static file in there works.

Comment: For people who are experiencing this;-

it was s3fs causing the problems - not or the first time. Basically, when mounting the bucket you **must** use the -o flag, allowing other users to use the mounted s3 dir. Unfortunately, if you don't do this everything appears fine, you can even chown and chmod dirs within - but it'll stop apache access and other service and commands... very painful.

    s3fs -o allow-others /bucketname/foo/bar